# Gemfury build fails with SyntaxError

Tags: python, build, package, python-packaging

I followed the initial setup at the [Gemfurey Dev docs](https://manage.fury.io/dashboard/jupytertools/push?kind=python) and when trying to `push` to the fury master branch, the build is triggered and fails with `SyntaxError`

```py
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (86/86)
remote: Initializing build: done.
remote: -----> Building package...
remote:        Python package build detected
remote:        File "setup.py", line 17
remote:        README: str = Path(HERE, "README.rst").read_text(encoding='utf-8')
remote:        ^
remote:        SyntaxError: invalid syntax
remote: -----> Problem building package!
```

I assume that the problem here is an incorrect version of python being run to build the package. I tried to check whether it is possible to [configure the build](https://gemfury.com/help/customize-git-build/) to use the correct python version -- in this case 3.6 -- but there is no hint of such possibility.

Anything I can do to make these automatic builds work or is my only option to build the package locally and upload it to the fury index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, ​Gemfury's current "git push" builder only supports Python 2 and there's no way to configure the runtime. If you're limited by this, I suggest building it locally or using another CI/CD solution to build and push it into your Gemfury account.